# GCP Spanner access attempts monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform, monitoring

I am looking to set up an alert that will monitor any invalid login attempts to Spanner. I already have a functional environment with Spanner, SA, and a few other services. I have also created a query to identify all invalid login attempts.

```
resource.type="spanner_instance"
  protoPayload.methodName=~"google.spanner.v1.Spanner..*CreateSession.*"
  protoPayload.authorizationInfo.granted!="true"
```

I created a service account without access to Spanner to test its functionality. Interestingly, this account now appears frequently in my logs, even though I'm not actively using it and I am unsure why.

Are there any other options for monitoring login attempts without having access?

Comment: Details matter to get a good answer. Edit your post and show the log entries for the service account.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Audit Logging](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/audit-logging). It automatically captures API calls to Spanner, including login attempts. It provides richer information like user identity, source IP, timestamp, and resource details. You can also filter logs based on specific metrics like failed attempts, unauthorized access, or unusual activity.

It's crucial to investigate why the service account without access is showing up in your logs. This could be due to various reasons, such as background tasks or system maintenance.

If you want to prevent your service account from appearing in your logs, you can disable its logging from the document I posted.